# Having issues applying solutions for iOS 7 status bar overlap

Tags: ios

I've got the issue where my iOS6 app's UI overlaps with the status bar on iOS 7. I've read previous posting on here regarding how to fix this but I'm not getting results.

I have several views all contained within a view controller's main view:

[image]

Posted solutions to the status bar overlap issue suggest to add 20 to the Y origin and set a value of -20 to the delta Y to compensate.

The first issue is I can't set the origin in IB for my main high level view  - its greyed out:
[image]

So instead in the VC's viewDidLoad a tried setting the origin manually:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   CGRect frame = self.view.frame;
   frame.origin.y = 20;
   self.view.frame = frame;
```

However when I run the app there's no difference, I'm still getting the status bar overlapping.

I'm only making changes to the main view, as all the other views are children of the main view I was assuming if I adjust just that one everything else will shift relative to that.

How come I'm not seeing any difference after making a change to the origin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this combined with your proposed solution in viewDidLoad:

`if ([self respondsToSelector:@selector(edgesForExtendedLayout)])
        self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;`

Another thing you can try is setting the frame on viewdidappear if this does not work for you.
Good luck and upvote up if this works for you :)

Comment: Thanks. If I move my code to viewDiAppear then it will shift down however: a) I don't understand why this is necessary - why can't the frame be set in viewDidLoad? b) the status bar is now a black bar and its items are visible. Why is it not visible?

Comment: A)The layout can happen after viewdidload. viewdidload is more or less signalling you that the view has loaded, doesnt necessarily means that its been laid out.
B)make sure you fix your views height accordingly, and that your app settings arent set to hide the status bar. (ALSO, use the if statement I provided.)